# Move all app windows to another work space in El Capitan

Tags: macos, spaces, mission-control

On my home machine (which is still on Mavericks) I can load mission control and move multiple windows from a single app by dragging the app icon (instead of the individual windows) to another work space.

This icon is not available in El Capitan, is there another way I can do this or at least a work around for it?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Enable “Group windows by application” in Mission Control preferences:

[image: System Preferences pane]

That will bring back the app icon in Mission Control, which would allow you to drag all windows of a given app between spaces:

[image: App icon in Mission Control]

Comment: YOU ARE MY HERO! ❤️

Answer (score 9):

There's a workaround, though not as efficient as your previous method...

Right click the App's icon in the Dock, select Options > All Desktops.
Switch to your preferred Space. [I use the  <kbd>Ctrl ⌃</kbd>   <kbd>[number]</kbd>  method.]
From the Dock again, turn the Option back to None.

[image]